# Mapping bigger grid attributes to overlapping smaller overlapping grids

Tags: grids-graticules

We have following grid structure.

[image]

There are certain attributes attached to the Bigger grid (80m). However we want to map all those attributes to smaller grids as it also contains some other attributes and is what we want to use. One approach is to use weights (by overlapping area percentage), but there are number of drawbacks. So is there any other approach we can use for this.

Comment: If you could please add some information to your question it would help allow people to provide detailed answers. What software are you using? Do you have any licensing constraints (ArcMap Basic only etc.). Have you tried anything already? If so, what did you try. Do you have any code you may have already used? If so, post it.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?